# Extracting blobs from Oracle - file damaged

Tags: oracle, pdf, plsql, blob

I have a few thousands documents stored as blobs in an Oracle 10g database. They are a mixture of .doc and pdf. I wish to extract them from Oracle onto the server for migration to another location.

Below is the sample code I am using to extract a single PDF. This appears to work successfully, up until I try and open the file using Adobe Reader. I get a message saying "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and cannot be repaired."

I have been able to export this PDF using the system front end and read it successfully, so the file is not corrupted on Oracle.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Many thanks.

```
DECLARE

  l_buffer    RAW(32767); --set buffer to maximum size
  l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767; --set amount to maximum size
  l_pos       NUMBER := 1;
  l_blob      BLOB;
  l_blob_len  NUMBER;

BEGIN

  select ff.blob_content
  into l_blob
  from documents pd
  where
      pd.id = '47820';

  l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_blob); --acquire blob size

  -- Open the destination file.
  l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('TEMP_DIR','test2511013','wb');        

  DBMS_LOB.read(l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);       

  UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE); 

  -- Close the file.
  UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only appear to write the first 32767 bytes of the LOB. Are you certain that the actual LOB length is within that limit? Also, what happens if the LOB length is below 32767 while you request to read 32767 bytes?

Comment: A very good question! my sample file appears to be 125899 bytes in length, which explains the file corruption. Thanks - I best investigate further now.